# Ping IP or URL from different IP with same Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ip, ping

how to ping a IP or URL from different location or IP with same Ubuntu  PC .

I want  access same IP or URL from the same Ubuntu PC but not with same system IP every time .

thank you.

Comment: you mean other than ssh-ing into a VPS or remote system and triggering the ping command, or finding an online ping tool that pings from their IP and not yours?

Comment: ping. should be done only from my Ubuntu but everytime not with same IP and Id love if it's. from command line .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control multiple machines (and have SSH access to them) you could use something like `dsh` to control them all at once, and by doing that, run something like:

```
dsh -M -c -a -- 'ping <<target_host>>'
```

Obviously that's going to require key-based access to all the hosts and you'll need to spend some time setting up `dsh` ([here's a tutorial](http://www.unixlore.net/articles/running-remote-commands-multiple-servers-ssh-dsh.html)).

---

The easier solution is to use an external tool like one of the many ping services... Pingdom, Monitor.us, CloundMonitor, etc. They'll all offer to ping your IP from dozens of IPs in various places around the world.

Comment: will take care of URL too ?>

Comment: It won't convert a full URL into a pingable domain name, but these will: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497215/extract-domain-name-from-url

Comment: but to check file path I need complete URL path too .

Comment: I don't understand. You can't `ping` a URL/document... It's just a network test.